Cannot create Neovim keybinding with special character "ö" in Tmux
I have a Swedish keyboard, and I want to bind <C-ö> to a special action in Neovim.
This works perfect when I open Neovim outside of Tmux, but when I open it in Tmux, it doesn't do anything. It does not register. I read here that tmux initially didn't support UTF-8, but it seems to do that now. I have tried enabling UTF-8 in .zshrc and in the tmux config to no success.
I'm not sure what else I can do.
